# Lazyloaded component and routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-lazyloading

I have a lazyloaded module called A.
I load A when navigating to 'a/comp1/:data1'.

In order to achieve it I declared in my app.module a route like this:

```
Path:'a',
loadChildren: () => import('./a/a.module').then(m => m.aModule)
```

In the A module I declare other routes like:

```
Path:'comp1/:data1'
Component: comp1
```

In my comp1 I have some fragments,
When I change the fragment, I  want to scroll to the fragment.
Actual behavior:
my comp1 is destroyed then re-inizialized (then it scrolls to the fragment).

Maybe I did something wrong. With the lazyLoad declaration?

How can I prevent the app to reload on fragment changed?

Comment: ahh? Not clear what you are asking

Comment: How can I prevent my component to be re-loaded on fragment changed?

Comment: what is a fragment?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=fragment+router+angular&oq=fragment+router+sngular&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.10705j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung-gj-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Good Luck he he he